# Clang doesn't know Doxygens retval tag

Tags: c, clang, doxygen

I'm trying to compile a C file with clang 3.6 and `-Weverything` but it fails at my Doxygen comment which includes the `\retval` tag.

My code looks like this:

```
/***************************************************************************/
/** Main Function.
 *
 * This function represents the main functionality.
 *
 * \retval 0 successful
 * \retval other failed
 */
int main(
    int argc,                               /**< argument count */
    char **argv                             /**< argument list */
)
{
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it with clang  I get the following warning.

```
$> clang-3.6 -Wall -Weverything -Werror -o main main.c
main.c:31:4: error: unknown command tag name [-Werror,-Wdocumentation-unknown-command]
 * \retval 0 successful
   ^
```

I know I can disable the warning by supplying `-Wno-documentation-unknown-command` but I think that's not the best solution.

Comment: It's the only sane solution. Either that or disable -Weverything.

Comment: While I'm a proponent of enabling lots of extra warnings, the `-Weverything` is quite frankly more than needed.

Comment: Or you could manually add those commands to clang...

Comment: Try specifying retval manually with -fcomment-block-commands

Comment: Unless you are traking down an actual problem `-Werror -Weverything` is usually pointless, because it literally turns on all available diagnostics - many of which are not warnings about code problems but things like this or optimization related information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment says, you can use the option:

```
-fcomment-block-commands=retval
```

This will stop clang from complaining about the tag \retval.